# RandomForestClassifier - Odd error with trying to identify feature importance in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to retrieve the importance of features within a RandomForestClassifier model, retrieving the coef for each feature in the model,

I'm running the following code here,

```
random_forest =  SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200, random_state = 123))
random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(random_forest.estimator.feature_importances_)
```

but am receiving the following error

```
NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? You can see I fit the model right before looking to identify the importance of features, but it doesn't seem to work as it should,

Similarily, I have the code below with a LogisticRegression model and it works fine,

```
log_reg = SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(class_weight = "balanced", random_state = 123))
log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(log_reg.estimator_.coef_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the attribute `estimator_` to access the **fitted** estimator (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html)). Observe that you forgot the trailing `_`. So it should be:

```
print(random_forest.estimator_.feature_importances_)
```

Interestingly, you did it correctly for your example with the `LogisticRegression` model.

Comment: Oh woops! I fat fingered and deleted the _ after estimator! Thank you!